# Numpy dot throws error

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays of the same dimension . When I tried to use dot product on them, I am getting "shapes not aligned" error.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2,4,6]])

Y = np.array([[1,0,1]])

np.dot(Y,A)



ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Can someone let me know why?

Thanks

Comment: Either (1, 3) x (3, 1) or (3, 1) x (1, 3) is possible. Try np.dot(Y, A.T) or np.dot(Y.T, A), where `.T` returns transpose array.

Comment: or alternatively define them as 1d vectors: `A = np.array([2,4,6])` (only 1 set of brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Row multiplies on column. You should transpose rows to columns first:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2,4,6]])
Y  = np.array([[1,0,1]])
np.dot(Y, A.T)
```

But maybe it is better to use `matrix` instead of `array` for matrix operations:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[2,4,6]])
Y  = np.matrix([[1,0,1]])
Y.dot(A.T)
```

Comment: Don't recommend np.matrix

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know transposing them will work, but my query is why it is throwing error even when the dimension is the same. As per broadcasting rule, it should work if both the dimensions are same.

Comment: @AbinJohnThomas, broadcasting rules don't apply to `np.dot`.  It has its own dimension rules.  Read them.